# State of being in a particular shape

Tags: meaning

Are there single words describing the "state of being in a particular shape"? [For Example: "State of being Cylindrical" ]

Comment: You mean like *cylindricality*?

Comment: Yea - is it a word? 

I am also looking for the feel/emotion into it

Answer (score 3):

If you want to express the bloviating verbosity that "X is in the state of being in a cylindrical shape", you simply say that "X is a cylinder" or that "X is cylindrical". Both sentences express the idea that "X is in the state of being in a cylindrical shape", only in 3 or 4 words instead of 11.

Comment: Kindly refer my answer to coleoptriest

Answer (score 2):

Collins has an entry for [cylindricity](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cylindricity):

> *the state or condition of being cylindrical*

Collins proffers a slightly different nuance for the following alternatives:

> [Cylindricality/cylindricalness](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cylindricality): *(geometry)* the quality or nature of being cylindrical.

But, in my opinion, all three words are largely synonymous.

As a generic term for all shapes, you would probably simply use *geometry*.

Comment: @Zuraiq *Cylindricality* isn't emotional, it's physical; and Mother Earth isn't cylindrical anyway. Please **edit your question** (don't add comments) to say exactly what you mean.

Comment: @Zuraiq: _Cylindricity_ is a geometric shape. Your usage of this word in "Zuraiq's Cylindricity is so pathetic" is essentially uncharted territory because it's metaphoric in a way that I don't understand. Unless it means that you're just a walking phallus (the phallus is essentially a cylinder with a piston at the top). In this case, I'd suggest that the question be migrated to SE.Writers.

Comment: @Andrew: I removed the comment

Comment: @Bill: Sorry for the examples that are metaphorical in nature.

Comment: @Zuraiq: There's nothing to apologize for. It's just that when you use language metaphorically, its appropriateness is a question for other creative writers rather than grammarians & usage mavens to comment on.